# React Native Animated flatlist item expander does not trigger onLayout of view

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to implement a flatlist where the items can be expanded to display additional data.
My problem is the onLayout() sometimes (~half the time) won't give me the full height of the content (won't return bigger height than 0 => cannot display the additional data)

This is my custom component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { Easing } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { Value, timing } = Animated;

export default class ResultElement extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 this.state = {
      expanded: false,
      contentHeight: 0,
    };

    this._initContentHeight = this._initContentHeight.bind(this);
 }

 height = new Value(0);

 toggle() {
    timing(this.height, {
      toValue: this.state.expanded ? 0 : this.state.contentHeight,
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
    }).start();
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }

  _initContentHeight(evt) {
    if (this.state.contentHeight > 0) return;
    const height = evt.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    this.setState({ contentHeight: height });
    this.height.setValue(this.state.expanded ? this.state.contentHeight : 0);
  }

  render() {
    const item = this.props.item;

    return (
      <View key={item.id}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.toggle(); }}>
            <Text>Toggle content below</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Animated.View style={[{ overflow: 'hidden' }, { height: this.height }]} onLayout={(evt) => this._initContentHeight(evt)}>
            <Text>Random Height content here</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the flatlist:

```js
<FlatList
  data={plan.timeline}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <ResultElement item={item} />}
  ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
/>
```

Can someone explain why the problem does not occurs all the time?

Comment: I replaced the flatlist with array.map, but the issue is still exists so the problem is the custom component. Still looking for how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Since I spent too much time debugging this issue without success, I decided to dump reanimated from this and use react native's built in solution:

In the screen:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
  }
}
```

I dumped flatlist and used scrollview instead with

```
array.map((item) => (<CustomComp props={yourprops} />)).
```

In the component, use:

```js
toggleExpand = () => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
}

...


{this.state.expanded &&
              <View>
                { item.type === 'driving' ? this._renderDrivingBody() :
                  item.type === 'point' ? this.renderPointBody() :
                    this.renderMinimumBody()}
              </View> }
```

That's all, hope it will help someone in the future.